# Is there any way to put Titanium code into Eclipse?

Tags: titanium

If Ive developed an Android app in Titanium (Appcelerator), is it possible to change it to use in Eclipse?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse, you can import your Titanium projects in eclipse but not with import but instead create a new web project and set the project location to the Titanium project you have created using Titanium developer.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Studio, the development environment for Titanium, **is** a branded and somewhat customized version of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I understand you write in Javascript in Titanium whereas Java in Eclipse, is there any way of transforming it into Java? I just have a project to write and Im not sure if I can change the language half way through, does it make a difference? Thank you

Comment: Uh, Eclipse is an IDE. It can handle any language, not just Java. You can't write Titanium code in anything but JavaScript, and Titanium-specific JavaScript at that. Changing the language of an app half way through is generally known as "starting over".

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you can put Titanium code within Eclipse:-

1. First be sure you have javascript Web development Eclipse version. You can download here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliossr1
2. After that you have to install plugin using Eclipse IDE.
3. Import Titanium’s mobile application into Eclipse for faste development.

For more information Check this link: http://www.eeblog.org/index.php/how-to-set-up-a-titanium-project-with-eclipse-and-start-our-first-mobile-application/